Google App Script to move "duplicated" sheet ( sheet 1/tab 1 ) to the end of the tabs and retaining the template
We need a template sheet that we can just duplicate and modify when needed and add to the report, and we need it to show up at the end every time someone creates a new copy of the sheet or tab.
This is the script I tried:
  function onEdit() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("TrackerTemplate").copyTo(ss).activate(); 
  ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets());
   }

My script is adding two additional duplicate tabs:
One next to the template tab/sheet and the other following the script and showing up at the end so I keep ending up having to delete the first duplicate

Improving onEdit Function
For better approach improving the function of onEdit.
Script modified
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var x = e.range.getA1Notation();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(x);

  var range = ss.getDataRange().getA1Notation();
    if(x == range){
    ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets());

    }
 
}

This condition is for the testing of your post you will need to adjust depends on your dataset also if you edit on the cell the active sheet will not moved into the last row
if(x == "A1:Z1000"){
ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets());
}

on this part
let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").copyTo(ss).activate(); 

This line is not needed since it will be redundant with the manual duplication your doing on the spreadsheet.
Sample Output



Reference

CopyTo 

getA1Notation

IF Statement



This isn't moving the copied tab to the far right

Hi @KarmelKwan, I updated my script and add this script var range = ss.getDataRange().getA1Notation(); , Please review the result to confirm if it meets your expectations. If not, kindly provide your expected result so I can adjust my response accordingly. If yes, Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the accept button on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that their problem can also be solved with this answer.
